# Redirect from Node Express server to client react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have set up my project as below:

[image: Folder structure]

The client is a react-app that runs on port 3000 and server.js runs on port 5000. I use concurrently to run both of them using a single terminal.

The block I am stuck with is that for a specific callback route in my server.js I want the user to be redirected to a client URL
`` res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/deposit/success`) ``

While hardcoding the client's URL works. How can I make it work if I want to deploy this project to Heroku?
How can I make server.js hosted on Heroku to look for my client react app which is also hosted on another port and redirect to that?

I have included the below snippet in my server.js :

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

  app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

and below proxy setting in client react app's package.json:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Comment: you can add env variable to your sever side code, and use that in redirect command: `res.redirect(\`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/deposit/success\`)`.  Heroku also provides options to put env variable inputs.